# Nested tables in a pdf using jspdf and jspdf-autotable

Tags: jspdf

How to achieve nested tables in a PDF using jspdf and jspadf-autotable? Something similar to the picture below:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Check this approach, together with html template and autotable . Created in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xsapyb)